# What does "%13s" or "%13d" stands for in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I cant find what `%(integer)(d s etc.)` conversation specifier stands for? What is the difference between `%s` and `%13s`?

Comment: for 's' that specify the length. is it to read or to print ?

Comment: As explained in [Format specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019).

Comment: This information is readily available https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Syntax

Comment: like printf("%s%13s\n", "Element", "Value")

Comment: "%[flags][width][.precision][size]type"

Comment: There is no way round this: please spend an hour reading about this very complicated family of functions, and trying things to get the feel of it all.

Answer (score 1):

> What does “%13s” or “%13d” stands for (?)
>   what %(integer)(d s etc.) (?)

`*printf`: The 13 or (integer) is the minimum print width - padding as needed.  At least that many characters will be printed.  Without the number, no padding is added.

`*scanf`: The 13 or (integer) is the maximum number of characters to read. Without the number, no max limit.

[Take time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373417/what-does-13s-or-13d-stands-for-in-c/61374735#comment108572417_61373417) to study `scanf()/printf()` - there is much more.